# drag drop for touch and desktop

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, touch, desktop-application

I'm making an application in WPF where i use drag and drop to drag items from one treeview to another. Al works well on a normal desktop application, but this should also work on a tablet.

I've heard about the surface sdk which has some drag and drop for touch but then the drag and drop functionality on the desktop application won't work anymore.

Anyone has any experience with implementing drag and drop for both desktop and touch environments?